# Where were Guadalupe Victoria's headquarters in Veracruz?

Tags: government, mexico

Mexico had a Provisional Government in 1823-1824, after the end of the First Mexican Empire. Guadalupe Victoria, a member of the governing triumvirate and the subsequent president, received an especial political mandate to run Veracruz, and during this period:

- in the port of Veracruz, he besieged the fort of San Juan de Ulúa
- at the fort of Puente Nacional, Veracruz, he held a *junta de guerra*, "in favor of the legitimately constituted authorities"
- in Xalapa, later state capital of Veracruz, he motivated a schism in a Masonic lodge

Where was Victoria's principal office as chief of Veracruz?